# Swift update deployment target to match package requirement

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm new to swift development, so excuse the basic question, but when I import a package called SwiftHttp in a local package, I get this error:

> Compiling for macOS 10.13, but module 'SwiftHttp' has a minimum deployment target of macOS 10.15:

So I've gone in to my project's setting, and changed the minimum  deployments to macOS 11.0, both in the "project" section, and for all targets, but that error remains in the file. Is there anywhere else I need to update that setting? Or is there something I need to do to "propagate" that setting to the local package?

Images of what I have...
Project settings:
[image]

Target settings
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: If you do CMD-SHIFT-F and search for 10.13, it will show it to you in project files too or anywhere else in the project it might be

Comment: No results found. Do I need to do anything special to have it include info.plist or sth?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build? Do that, and also (1) exit Xcode (2) run `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` (3) open Xcode and try again

Comment: Yep, I just tried that, and it didn't work so far. Just to check, to do a clean build, all I needed to do is "clean build folder", and then build again, right?

Comment: Yes, and the DerivedData removal is even more "clean". I think I would remove the package and the import, get everything building and then add it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by explicitly setting a supported platform version in `package.swift` in my own package, which I use" in this project. The relevant part now looks like this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Swiftodon",
    platforms: [
            .macOS(.v10_15),
            .iOS(.v13),
            .tvOS(.v13),
            .watchOS(.v6)
        ],
```